# Why doesn't this generic assignment work?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have a method like so:

```
<T extends ImportedGroupTxtContact> Importer<T> createImporter(Class<T> classToImport)
```

In the method body this is fine:

```
ParseResult<? extends ImportedGroupTxtContact, ?> parseResult = new ParseResult<ImportedGroupTxtContact, ChildContactField<?>>();
```

Yet this is not:

```
ParseResult<T, ?> parseResult = new ParseResult<ImportedGroupTxtContact, ChildContactField<?>>();
```

This makes no sense to me, as `T extends ImportedGroupTxtContact` has the same upper bound as `? extends ImportedGroupTxtContact`.  What exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` extends `ImportedGroupTxtContact`. So it could be any subclass of `ImportedGroupTxtContact`. Let's replace that with `Fruit`. Apple extends Fruit. But you can't do

```
Basket<Apple> basket = new Basket<Fruit>();
```

Indeed, a `Basket<Apple>` only accepts apples, whereas a `Basket<Fruit>` accepts any kind of Fruit.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a `ParseResult<A, B>` to `ParseResult<T, ?>` where `T` may or may not be equal to `A`, so this must fail. More precisely, `T` can be any subtype of `A`. The fact that `T` and the `?` from your first example both have the same upper bound doesn't enter the equation here.